# Need to update FK with new PK on duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I've got two tables - tonight I'm honestly believing I'm having a blonde moment.

## Headings

```
HeadingID, HeadingName, TopicID
```

## SubHeadings

```
SubHeadingID, SubHeadingName, HeadingID
```

What I'd like to do is to duplicate all entries in Headings and `SubHeadings` where `TopicID` = 1 to = 2.

I've written:

```
INSERT INTO Headings (HeadingName, TopicID)
SELECT HeadingName, 2 FROM Headings WHERE TopicID = 1  //(Duplicating Headings and assigning TopicID 2).
```

I'm stuck on the `SubHeadings`; I'd like to put in the new `HeadingID` that has just been created and I've got no idea.  I can do the rest of the fields with the same Insert/Select statement however I'm stumped.

Can someone please help me out with an example or some documentation please?

Simplified the data looks like this:

```
HeadingID = 1
HeadingName = 'News'
TopicID = 1
HeadingID = 2
HeadingName = 'Sport'
TopicID = 1

SubHeadingID = 1
SubHeadingName = 'Local'
HeadingID = 1
SubHeadingID = 2
SubHeadingName = 'National'
HeadingID = 1
SubHeadingID = 3
SubHeadingName = 'International'
HeadingID = 1
SubHeadingID = 4
SubHeadingName = 'Baseball'
HeadingID = 2
SubHeadingID = 5
SubHeadingName = 'Cricket'
HeadingID = 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query will help you :)

```
INSERT INTO SubHeadings (SubHeadingName, HeadingID) 
SELECT subhdng.SubHeadingName, hdng.HeadingID 
FROM Headings hdng
INNER JOIN SubHeadings subhdng ON hdng.HeadingID = subhdng.HeadingID 
WHERE hdng.TopicID = 2
```

Comment: @jetgrrrl please let me know if above answer helps.

Comment: Thanks OMG, I'll test it when I wake up :D

Comment: Hi OMG, your suggestion wasn't working however the join gave me another idea (inserting an inline select to get the headingid) and I was able to get it from there :)  Thanks!